# Custom tableHeaderView with snapkit?

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I have a custom view that assign to tableHeaderView. I used snapkit to made  custom view layout. I have run some errors, I don't know how to solve it . Please help me, Thanks. Here is my code:

In my ViewController:

```
class QuestionDetailController: BaseViewController {

lazy var tableView = DefaultManager.createTableView()
lazy var dataSource: [HomeListItemModel] = []
lazy var hearderView: QuestionDetailHearderView = QuestionDetailHearderView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupTableView()
    navigationItem.title = "问题详情"
}

func setupTableView() {
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.setDelegate(self,self)
    tableView.tableHeaderView = hearderView
    registerCell()
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    tableView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.left.right.top.bottom.equalToSuperview()
    }
    tableView.sizeHeaderToFit()
}

func registerCell() {
    tableView.register(LargeImageViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: LargeImageViewCell.idenfitier)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }
 }

extension QuestionDetailController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let large = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: LargeImageViewCell.idenfitier, for: indexPath) as! LargeImageViewCell
    large.titleLabel.text = "hello"
    return large
   }
 }
```

The extension of UITableView contain sizeHeaderToFit():

```
extension UITableView{

func sizeHeaderToFit() {
    if let headerView = self.tableHeaderView {
        let height = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height

        var newFrame = headerView.frame
        newFrame.size.height = height
        headerView.frame = newFrame

        headerView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
 }
}
```

My custom view like this:

```
class QuestionDetailHearderView: UIView {

lazy var tagView: TagView = TagView()
lazy var questionLabel = UILabel().then {
    $0.setLabel(AppTheme.Colors.title, 19.5)
    $0.withNumberOfLines(0)
}
lazy var contentLabel = UILabel().then {
    $0.setLabel(AppTheme.Colors.content3, 14.5)
}
lazy var threeImageView: ThreeImageView = ThreeImageView()
lazy var answerLabel = UILabel().then {
    $0.setLabel(AppTheme.Colors.auxiliary2, 14.5)
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupUI()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func setupUI() {
    addSubview(tagView)
    addSubview(questionLabel)
    addSubview(contentLabel)
    addSubview(threeImageView)
    addSubview(answerLabel)
    addUIConstraints()
}

func addUIConstraints() {
    tagView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.left.equalToSuperview().offset(AppDefaults.Constants.space13)
        make.right.equalToSuperview().offset(-AppDefaults.Constants.space13)
        make.top.equalToSuperview().offset(AppDefaults.Constants.space16)
        make.height.equalTo(30)
    }

    tagView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow

    questionLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.left.right.equalTo(tagView)
        make.top.equalTo(tagView.snp.bottom).offset(AppDefaults.Constants.space15)
    }
    questionLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    contentLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.left.right.equalTo(questionLabel)
        make.top.equalTo(questionLabel.snp.bottom).offset(AppDefaults.Constants.space13)
    }
    contentLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan

    threeImageView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.left.right.equalTo(contentLabel)
        make.top.equalTo(contentLabel.snp.bottom).offset(AppDefaults.Constants.space13)
        make.height.equalTo(77)
    }

    answerLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.left.right.equalTo(threeImageView)
        make.top.equalTo(threeImageView.snp.bottom).offset(AppDefaults.Constants.space13)
        make.bottom.equalToSuperview().offset(-AppDefaults.Constants.space16)
    }
    answerLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan

   // updateData()
}
}
```

Here is some part of the error:

```
 [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(<SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x1740b5ae0@QuestionDetailHearderView.swift#47 ZhiMa_iOS.TagView:0x103850290.left == ZhiMa_iOS.QuestionDetailHearderView:0x10384fed0.left + 13.0>",
"<SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x1740b7e20@QuestionDetailHearderView.swift#48 ZhiMa_iOS.TagView:0x103850290.right == ZhiMa_iOS.QuestionDetailHearderView:0x10384fed0.right - 13.0>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17009fcc0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' ZhiMa_iOS.QuestionDetailHearderView:0x10384fed0.width == 0   (active)>"
 )

  Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
     <SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x1740b7e20@
    QuestionDetailHearderView.swift#48 
      ZhiMa_iOS.TagView:0x103850290.right == 
      ZhiMa_iOS.QuestionDetailHearderView:0x10384fed0.right - 13.0>
 Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to 
 catch this in the debugger.
 The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView 
 listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: Try setting translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false for headerView. Looks like there's a constraint conflict between SnapKit and native constraints that iOS makes.

Comment: @user1537360, yeah, it works.